# I need to find a formula without using Schröder-Bernstein Theorem and Im stuck.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let A={Infinite length binary strings with finitely many 1's} I need to find an explicit formula to prove that set A is countable.

Comment: Like, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k2^k$ ?

Comment: No I need to find a bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Like $a\mapsto\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k2^k$ ?

Comment: Oh I get it now, like only the 1's are going to sum up so the output is in $\mathbb{N}$ and its a surjection and injection since we can get every $x\in\mathbb{N}$(uniquely) by adding powers of two . Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, that's about the size of it.